# Karate UI Script Invalid Handshake

Tags: karate

Karate UI feature files failing with a bad handshake
Here is the code below, just a basic feature file which opens up the angular site

````
Background
configure cors = true
configure driver = {type: 'chrome', executable: 'chrome', addOptions: '\[*--remote-allow-origins=*\]}
Scenario: User goes to Angular
Given driver 'https://angular.io'
And fullscreen()
Then assert locate('.nav-link.home').exists```

/////////Error I am getting that is a web socket issue
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: driver config / start failed: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 403 Forbidden, options: {type=chrome, target=null}
classpath:features/testing.feature:8
       at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:38)
       at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:135)
       at com.intuit.karate.junit5.FeatureNode.lambda$next$1(FeatureNode.java:86)
       at ```
````

Comment: sounds like the chrome you are using or have installed is not something karate expects. I think the best way forward is some investigation on why that is the case, this is not something anyone has reported before

Answer (score 1):

```
Feature: Test Feature

  Background: 
    * configure cors = true
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }

  Scenario: User goes to Angular
    Given driver 'https://angular.io'
    And fullscreen()
    Then match exists('.nav-link.home') == true
```

Html Report:
[image]